# Encoding service class methods Parameters during runtime based on type

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, postsharp

I was recently looking at postsharp to try to auto-encode all parameters on an asmx webservice without rewriting the whole webservce, this from my thinking would go along this route.
     1.Create a MethodInterceptApsect class from Postsharp to handle the parameters.
     2.Apply the Aspect to my Webservice class
     3.In the aspect, change / encode all values of type string

In my test application this worked, but it failed when it came to using the javascript webservice, this from my understanding is because of the way asmx calls are handled, is there a way this can be achieved using postsharp? Intercepting webservice calls and changing parameter values before they are sent to the service?

Comment: This should be possible to achieve with PostSharp. First of all, I would check that you have Web Application, not Web Site project (i.e. you have actual *.csproj file in your project).

Comment: I have a csproj file but my implementation fails.I will post more details on what I have tried in the morning